# Unable to store / retrieve cookie in a spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, cookies

In my current spring-boot project, I add this class with the goal to allow me store and retrieve cookies:

```
public class CookieAcessor {
  public static List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
    try {
      CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
      manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
      CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
      CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
      URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
      List <HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.get(url.toURI());
      return cookies;
    } catch(Exception e) {
      return new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
    }
  }

  public static String getCookie(String key) {
    List<HttpCookie> cookies = getCookies();
    for(HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
      if(cookie.getName().equals(key))
        return cookie.getValue();
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void setCookie(String key, String value) {
    try {
      CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
      CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
      CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
      HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
      URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
      cookieJar.add(url.toURI(), cookie);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Erro ao armazenar o cookie!");
    }
  }
}
```

but when I try execute any methods from this class (for read or save a cookie), nothing is done. Anyone can see what's wrong with this code? It was based on this article from official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html.

**UPDATE**

this class is used in a method from controller like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public String index() {
    CookieAcessor.setCookie("teste", "...");
    System.out.println("cookie[teste] = "+CookieAcessor.getCookie("teste"));
    return "public/index";
  }
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the request to get cookies and the response to set cookies? What you do here seems way to complex and will only work for cookies on localhost port 8080 if you change things, this class will simply break...

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't use request/response to get/set cookies because I am not using this on my controller (see the example I add to question). Is there any way to retrieve this two elements without add something like `(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)` to my methods?

Comment: Just add those, for retrieving cookies you can also simply add those to your method as an argument annotated with [`@CookieValue`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CookieValue.html).

Comment: The solution you posted is for a client side application (like an applet or Java Web Start application) not a server side application. Those are quite different use cases...